# Gestation period of African savanna elephants?

Tags: zoology, mammals, pregnancy

I found out it is 22 months for African bush elephants, but is this also true for African savanna elephants?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [African *bush* elephant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/African_bush_elephant) and the African *savannah* elephant are the same species (i.e., they are just different names for *Loxodonta africana*).

According to [here](http://www.nhm.org/site/explore-exhibits/permanent-exhibits/african-mammals/savanna-elephant) and [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/African_bush_elephant), the African savanna/bush elephant (*Loxodonta africana*) has a [gestation period](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gestation) of 22 months.

The only other African species of elephant, the [African forest elephant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/African_forest_elephant) (*Loxodonta cyclotis), has a gestation period of 20 - 22 months (see [here](http://animaldiversity.org/accounts/Loxodonta_cyclotis/)). Both [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/African_forest_elephant) and [this source](http://wildpro.twycrosszoo.org/S/0MProboscidae/Elephantidae/Loxodonta/Loxodonta_cyclotis/Loxodonta_cyclotis.htm) corroborate this higher expected range of 22 months, but with the latter source adding:

> from zoo data a gestation length averaging 660 days has been determined while the average in one wild population (Amboseli) was 656 days.

And for fun, click below for a video of an elephant fetus!

[image]

Comment: Pink elephants - I must be on acid; comes close to a blue dart frog :D +1 for the well illustrated answer